# Find the position of the most similar word sequence within larger text

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, nlp, full-text-search

I have some sequence of words as input (e.g. a sentence or part of a sentence). I'm looking for a way to find the position and contents of the most similar substring within a larger text, as well as some sort of similarity score.

The matching substring can contain typos, similarly sounding words, or fewer/extra words, compared to the input string.

Is there an established way to do this? I could only find answers for how to directly compare two strings for similarity, but nothing about finding the position and similarity score of the closest match within a text.

I'm more interested in matches in terms of characters and/or how stuff sounds, rather than meaning.

Ideally looking for a way to achieve this in JavaScript, but language-agnostic suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: There is an algorithm called [dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). Is that what you want?

Comment: @Kisar Probably not, unless I'm misunderstanding it. It sounds like this will compare two texts for similarity. What I'm looking for instead is this: given a sentence or part of sentence, find the most similar occurence within a larger body of text.

Comment: I see how that could be confusing. The algorithm described in the article is only one half of what you want to do. I've expanded on this as proper answer.

Comment: Considering that you have not defined "similar" there is no objective basis for answering this question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thought I did - "The matching substring can contain typos, similarly sounding words, or fewer/extra words, compared to the input string". Is that too vague? I should probably clarify that I'm looking for the most similarity in terms of characters and/or sounds rather than meaning.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is [dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

It's an algorithm for calculating a similarity score between two sequences, but it can also be used to find the places *where* the similarities are. Consider the pseudocode in the linked article (May 3rd 2022, if it has changed in the meantime). You probably want to use the second version which includes the locality constraint.

Extend the algorithm as follows: after calculating the DTW array, you can iterate your way backwards from `DTW[n,m]` towards `DTW[0,0]` by always going towards the previous minimum value. I. e. if your current position is `[i,j]` then your next position is `[k,l]` for which `DTW[k,l]` is minimal out of the three possible positions

1. `k=i-1, l=j`
2. `k=i-1, l=i-1`
3. `k=i,   l=j-1`

Assuming your text is in the first dimension and your "substring" on the second one, you have the following correspondences:

1. The text has a character at position `i` that doesn't appear in the best matching.
2. The text has a character at position `i` that appears at position `j` in the best matching.
3. The text does not contain the character at position `j` in the best matching string.

The greatest `k` for which `[k,0]` appears in the backwards iteration and the smallest `l` for which `[l,m]` appears will be the beginning and end of the best matching sequence in your text.